# Location.getTime() show wrong date when android OS date and timezone is changed

Tags: android, timezone, location, locationmanager

When we change Android OS date-time and `Timezone` then `Location.getTime()` also reflect with changed date.
So how to get original date-time from Location while android Os date-time is wrong.